# Git rebase, change order of added functions, resolve conflict, understand merge

Tags: git, pycharm

I am in a separate branch (`genericatt-wip`) and I want to cleanup a list of commits. I.e. I rebase onto current `master`. [image: rebase-screen]
Many of these commits (all these `test_...` commits) add a single new function (a new test case). This is the original list: [image: rebase-initial-screen]
When changing the order of these, I get a conflict, although in principle there is no conflict (all these commits just add things, and all of them add separate individual functions). I wonder a bit about that, although I guess that Git just gets confused because the order of how these functions are being added to the file is not clear (right?). Although that does not matter to Python, but I guess Git is not clever enough about that (maybe off topic here: is there some way to auto-resolve such problems with a more intelligent merger?).

Specifically, I now change the order of a single commit: [image: rebase-change-screen]
I.e. I moved this `test_..._extra_spatial` commit a bit down.
Now I get this conflict message:[image: conflict-msg-screen]
In the terminal, `git status` now shows me this:

```
interactive rebase in progress; onto d5530561
Last commands done (4 commands done):
   pick 863c746d GenericAttentionLayer wip
   pick e9443620 test_GenericAttentionLayer_weights_auto_squeeze_time_end
  (see more in file .git/rebase-merge/done)
Next commands to do (15 remaining commands):
   pick 2c6b3bfa test_GenericAttentionLayer_weights_heads_auto_squeeze_time_end
   pick 269eb63e test_GenericAttentionLayer_weights_heads_time_end
  (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)
You are currently rebasing branch 'genericatt-wip' on 'd5530561'.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
  (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   tests/test_TFNetworkRecLayer.py

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

The content of `.git/rebase-merge/done` is:

```
pick 2260330b4253c94ef662c641c61204ce14ba1e29 test_GenericAttentionLayer_basic
pick 85c0f36048b451911820aa44dff316970d644609 test_rec_layer_move_out_of_loop_ref_att_generic_att
pick 863c746d56ae96f24bbada41fd4d0973ec5d1579 GenericAttentionLayer wip
pick e9443620401e2d50a2dede65101e98f567ca724d test_GenericAttentionLayer_weights_auto_squeeze_time_end
```

So, it says that these commands were done, but I guess it means the last command (`pick e9443... test_...weights_auto_squeeze_time_end`) is not done yet, but this is actually the command it currently tries to apply, which fails with the commit, right? When I do `git show e94436...`, I see that this commit adds the function `test_..._weights_auto_squeeze_time_end` (and nothing else), i.e. it shows:

```
commit e9443620401e2d50a2dede65101e98f567ca724d
...

    test_GenericAttentionLayer_weights_auto_squeeze_time_end

diff --git a/tests/test_TFNetworkRecLayer.py b/tests/test_TFNetworkRecLayer.py
index 7d39d604..efc80499 100644
--- a/tests/test_TFNetworkRecLayer.py
+++ b/tests/test_TFNetworkRecLayer.py
@@ -2682,6 +2682,26 @@ def test_GenericAttentionLayer_basic():
   ...


+def test_GenericAttentionLayer_weights_auto_squeeze_time_end():
+  ...
+
+
 def test_GenericAttentionLayer_extra_spatial():
   ...
```

Looking into that code file directly at this state, I see this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
def test_GenericAttentionLayer_weights_auto_squeeze_time_end():
  ...


def test_GenericAttentionLayer_extra_spatial():
  ...


>>>>>>> e9443620... test_GenericAttentionLayer_weights_auto_squeeze_time_end
```

Clicking on 'Merge' gives me this interface:[image: merge-screen]
This brings me to my main question(s) here:

I don't quite understand the interface. What exactly do I see on the left, middle and right side? What does it mean by "Your version, branch `genericatt-wip`", "Result", and "Changes from branch `.../master`, rev 85..."?

This is the intermediate state of applying (cherry-picking) a single commit onto `master` + other commits it has already applied before, right? But where do I see which other commits it has already applied before? And where do I see which commit it is currently trying to apply?

It seems that on the left side, two functions are added, in the middle, one function is added, and on the right, no function is added. But this diff is shown with respect to what? Why are there two functions added on the left? Every commit only adds a single function, so how can that happen?

Where/how do I see what the currently applied commit will change? So where do I see what it was before, what it will be after, and what the change is? So, basically, I know that the change of each commit should be exactly to add one function, but I'm not sure how I can see that this is happening.

(The interface is from PyCharm, but I'm not sure how relevant this is. These questions are probably generic to Git.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can answer two thirds of your question here - why there is a conflict, and how to figure out what's going on. I don't know the PyCharm interface so I can only guess at what it's showing you.

**Why the conflict**

In the screen capture you show, the cause for the conflict is that you have a commit that adds a block contiguous to a block that doesn't exist yet, because you've chosen to rebase it later in the sequence: I think you're adding `test...spatial()` after `test...end()`, but the latter doesn't exist yet. I'm assuming it'll get added when the commit that adds it is considered later.

When Git sees contiguous changes, it will not forge ahead because that would require guessing and that would not always be safe. You have to review those and resolve the conflict to say what is the correct result.

**How to know what's going on**

I've reproduced your scenario by adding "line1" at the end of file `a` in a commit followed by adding "line2" in a second commit:

```
$ git log --format=oneline master
0a3b254 (master) line2
ef7e059 line1
```

Now I rebase to reverse these two commits and get a conflict when I pick `0a3b254` before `ef7e059` and the command-line command tells me which commit has a conflict and stops there:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD^^
Auto-merging a
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in a
error: could not apply 0a3b254... line2
```

Now, you're using a different interface, so I don't know if it shows the problem commit, but `git status` will do so, if you run it on the command line:

```
$ git status
interactive rebase in progress; onto bf27dcb
Last command done (1 command done):
   pick 0a3b254 line2
Next command to do (1 remaining command):
   pick ef7e059 line1
```

Now I can inspect the commit I'm trying to rebase with `git show 0a3b254` and it shows me adding "line2" after "line1".

I can also look at `a` to see what the conflict is:

```
$ cat a
asdf
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
line1
line2
>>>>>>> 0a3b254... line2
```

This tells me that in `master`, there were no lines here (between `<<<<<<< HEAD` and `=======`) and that in `0a3b254`, I have two lines. The way I know which ones to keep is by doing `git show 0a3b254` because there is nothing in `a` at this point telling me what to keep.

So I resolve the conflict by keeping only "line2" from my version and continue the rebase:

```
# edit a to keep just line2
git add a
git rebase --continue
...
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in a
error: could not apply ef7e059... line1
```

Again, I get a conflict again with ef7e059 because two blocks were added at the same place and Git certainly won't know in what order to keep place them.

```
$ cat a
asdf
<<<<<<< HEAD
line2
=======
line1
>>>>>>> ef7e059... line1
```

Here Git tells me I added line2 in a previous commit on `HEAD` and line1 in the commit I'm currently working on, ef7e059. This is not helpful to figure out the correct order, nor is `git show ef7e059`, but `git show mybranch:a` shows me the contents of `a` in the original branch (since the branch is not updated until the rebase is complete) and helps me figure out that I need to insert line2 after line1.

```
# edit a to place its contents in the right order
git add a
git rebase --continue
```

**Speculation about the PyCharm GUI**

In your interface, I'm expecting Result (center pane) is where you have to place the outcome of the conflict resolution, the left pane is probably the state of the code in the commit being cherry picked, and the right pane is probably the state of the code onto which the cherry-pick is happening.

Based on the comments to this answer and the addition information you showed in the question, I would guess Result contains the wrong function, which you might have to replace by the one that this commit is actually trying to add.

There's no harm in trying: you can always try and see if it works, and revert the rebase later if the final results are not identical (according to `git diff`) to the code before the rebase.

Comment: I edited my question to also show `git status`. About the `git status` output: E.g. `Last command done (1 command done)` in your output is a bit misleading, as this last command is actually not done yet, right? This is exactly the command currently in progress, which fails with the conflict. Maybe you can clarify that.

Comment: You say that it looks like Git guessed correctly. But the current commit being picked (`e9443620...`) would add the function `test_..._weights_auto_squeeze_time_end`, and not the function `test_..._extra_spatial`, as I see in the center in "Result". So this is wrong, or not?

Comment: @Albert The "Last command done" is the one that is in progress, but not completed because of the conflict. So it tells you the commit to pay attention to.

Comment: @Albert If it is currently picking `e9443620 test_GenericAttentionLayer_weights_auto_squeeze_time_end` then it indeed looks like you'll have to put it in manually to resolve the conflict, you're right. And maybe `extra_spatial()` should not be in the results at all, if it is in a commit coming later down.

Comment: Thanks for clarification (but maybe better add this to your answer, not here as a comment). Btw, I now also added the content of the file at this state (with `<<<... HEAD`, `===...` and `>>>...`), which similar to what the GUI shows. Maybe you can explain that?

Comment: PS: I removed the line about Git having guessed correctly, since it didn't. I'll look at the content of the file at this state - that I *can* read. :) More in a bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This almost clarifies everything. One last thing: In the GUI, in the left pane, it has one of the functions with lighter red background than the other. This probably means something. But what exactly? And about just trying out: I should make sure though that I remember the original commit hash, right?

Comment: Well, `git reflog` will tell you where you were in the past, so you can always recover the original commit hash. It's not a bad idea to take a note of it before you start, but it's not necessary. Mind you, I'd probably create a duplicate branch `git checkout -b dev.playing-with-rebase` to make it even easier to backtrack. Happy this helped!

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the light and dark pink are meaningful. I expect you'll figure it out once you've used this tool multiple times and seen these colours in different contexts.

Comment: Maybe a last question: Git knows that you add only `line2` in your commit `0a3b254`. So why can't it be more helpful in marking this somehow? The conflict shown in the file (with `<<<... HEAD`, `===...` and `>>>...`) is very confusing in this case. Are there tools / tricks to make this more straight forward? I guess that I would easily make mistakes in such situations, when I'm not super careful in checking what the commit actually did change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189145/discussion-between-joanis-and-albert).